# Как проверить, присутствует ли пара ключ-значение в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

b = {'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Проверить наличие **b** в **a**, и на выходе значение типа `bool`

Пробовал такое решение:

```
b.items() <= a.items()
```

Так же возникла проблема с словарем такого типа:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}], 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

b = {'c': 3, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}]}
```

Но его проверить таким способом не получится

```
 b.items() <= a.items()
```

Ищу другие решения данной проверки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818694/test-if-dict-contained-in-dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2,'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
b = {'a': 1, 'c': 3}

if len(b.items() & a.items()) == len(b):
    print(True, len(b.items() & a.items()), b.items() & a.items())
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# 1
b.items() <= a.items()

# 2
b.items() in a.items()

# 3
flag = True
for key in b:
    try:
        if a[key] != b[key]:
            flag = False
    except KeyError:
        flag = False
```

Comment: `except KeyError:`

Comment: @andreymal благодарю за уточнение.

Answer (score 1):

```py
a={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}

b={'a':1,'c':3}

def check(items: tuple):
  return items in a.items()

print(all([*map(check, b.items())]))
```

Ну или без заморочек с функцией:

```py
a={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}

b={'a':1,'c':3}


print(all([item in a.items() for item in b.items()]))
```

Comment: в обоих случаях можно не ставить `[]`. `all(map(check, b.items())`; `all(item in a.items() for item in b.items())`

Comment: еще можно использовать лямбду вместо `check`: `lamba item: item in a.items()`

Comment: @Namerek Спасибо за решение! А если словари такого типа: a = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}], 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5} b = {'c': 3, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}]}. И нужно так же проерить наличие b в a

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(a, b):
    if b.items() <= a.items():
       try:
           for key in b:
               if b[key] != a[key]:
                   return False
       except KeyError:
           return False
       else:
           return True
    else:
        return False
```

P.S. немного отредактированный ответ [n1tr0xs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/368899/n1tr0xs)